# where can i do a testnet Lightning Network Reverse Submarine Swap?

Tags: lightning-network, atomic-swap

i have Testnet LN Node,
i have created a wallet,
i have send on-chain funds to that wallet
i have connected to several peers
i have created several channels, all of these are outgoing one side funded channels,

i want to do a reverse submarine swap, i mean Pay in LN and receive in BTC

LN --> BTC

this site offers the other way https://submarineswaps.org/

the purpose of these is to reverse a channel, or the half capacity of channel to be ready to receive LN payments.

of course i could just spend money, but the idea is to reverse the channel without loosing money (loosing is simulated as its in testnet)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try [sideshift.ai](https://sideshift.ai) or zigzag.io the first one supports testnet but is still invoite only. For [zigzag.io](https://zigzag.io) I think this service is only offered on mainnet.

Answer (score 1):

As of now this is possible with [Lightning Labs' Loop](https://github.com/lightninglabs/loop).  It's a non-custodial reverse submarine swap implementation.

- You need to build LND with some special flags to enable the feature.
- Loop is installed and runs separately as a daemon.

Once you have both running, you can simply "loop out" to send balance in your channel and receive Bitcoin onchain.

Comment: could it be done with an Eclairs Android mobile wallet channel?

Comment: @emi only for a channel between Eclair mobile wallet and an LND node that's running loopd. Then you can provide loop the channel id.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trusted service for now but it utilizes the Lightning Loop to do a reverse submarine swap https://reckless.capital/swap

At the moment of writing this website is on the Lightning Testnet. Soon this service will be available for use on Mainnet.

Also **full disclosure I am the owner of the website.**